# Jquery/ajax loaded table not showing on IE 9

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I have a table loaded by Jquery/AJAX

```
function initializeDaily() {
jQuery.post(
        'ajax-functions.php', 
        {
            'action':'getdailyStatus'
        }, 
        function(response){
            var html = response
            $('#daily_result').append(html) //append to table #daily_result

            var rowid = $('#daily_result tr:first-child').attr('id')

            getDetails(rowid)
        })
}
```

This will work on all other browser and not on IE9. getDetails(rowid) will work, so I do not believe there are syntax errors

on the other hand, if I did this:

```
function initializeDaily() {
jQuery.post(
        'ajax-functions.php', 
        {
            'action':'getdailyStatus'
        }, 
        function(response){
            var html = '    <table id="daily_result" cellspacing="0">'+"\n"
            html += response
            html += '   </table>'+"\n"  
            $('#data_scroll').html(html) //div that holds the table

            var rowid = $('#daily_result tr:first-child').attr('id')

            getDetails(rowid)
        })
}
```

The table loads alright but my `$("#daily_result").on("click", "tr", function(event))` does not work.

Is there a work around of this?
It will be of great help if anyone can tell me what went wrong =)

**Edit

ok...I managed to get it to work. However, I do not think that this is the best way to do it.

this is what I did:

```
 jQuery.post( //its still post
    'ajax-functions.php', 
    {
        'action':'getdailyStatus'
    }, 
    function(response){
        var html = response

        $('#data_scroll').html(html)

        var rowid = $('#daily_result tr:first-child').attr('id')

        //moved my event handler here; after the loading of the table
        $("#daily_result").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "tr", function(event){
            if(event.type == "mouseenter"){
                $(this).css("background","#999")
                $(this).css("color","#FFF")
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr('style')
            }
        })
        getDetails(rowid)
    })
```

Is there any way I can do this better?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you try jQuery.load

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#daily_result').load('ajax-functions.php', {
            'action':'getdailyStatus'
        }, function(){
            var rowid = $('#daily_result tr:first-child').attr('id')
            getDetails(rowid)
        });
```

Comment: yes. it is able to get from '#daily_result tr:first-child' and execute the getDetails(rowid) function